# fscanf with string and long

Tags: c, csv, scanf, ansi-c

I'm trying to parse a file that another function has written with this fprintf:

```
fprintf(file, "DS;%s;%ld;%ld;%u\n", ds->name, ds->start, ds->period, ds->size)
```

I'm using this fscanf:

```
fscanf(file, "DS;%[^;$]s;%ld;%ld;%u", file_name, &file_start, &file_period, &file_size)
```

file_name is read with no problems. but file_start, file_period and file_size are always 0, even if not expected.

For exemple, the string:

```
DS;failures;1363978800;600;144
```

Is parsed like this:

- **file_name**: failures (ok)
- **file_start**: 0 (ko)
- **file_period**: 0 (ko)
- **file_size**: 0 (ko)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the return value? That will tell you how many conversions it did, if it's not 4 then you're not quite correct in saying that the fields are parsed to 0, they're not parsed at all (not changed by `fscanf()`).

Comment: don't know exactly the return value. But it's greater than 0 because I test the scanf for errors checking its return.

Answer (score 3):

replace the string format `"%[^;$]s"` by this `%[^;$]` ==> remove the `s` because `[]` replace the `s` so no need any more for `s`